# My react website freezes after moving element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, freeze

I am a beginner in React and currently I would like to create a car which could move after hitting arrow keys. However, after some time this website freezes and I am not even able to open the console.

**My parent component**

```
function App() {
    
    const [move, setMove] = useState("Standing");
    
      return (
        <>
        <h1 id="move">{move}</h1>
        <Car currentMove={move} whereMove={setMove} />
        </>
      )
    }
```

**My child component**

```
const Car = (props) => {

    let [x, setX] = useState(50);
    let [y, setY] = useState(50);

    let itemStyle = {
        top: y + "%",
        left: x + "%",
        color: "goldenrod"
    }

    window.addEventListener("keydown", event => startCar(event))

    function startCar(event) {
        console.log(event);
        switch (event.keyCode) {
            case 38:
                setY(y - 2);
                break;
            case 40:
                setY(y + 2);
                console.log(itemStyle);
                break;
            case 37:
                setX(x - 1);
                break;
            case 39:
                setX(x + 1)
                break;
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
        <div className="car" style={itemStyle}>X</div>
        </>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to move the eventListener to `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  // on component mount
  window.addEventListener("keydown", startCar)

  // on component unmount
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", startCar)
  }
}, [])
```

Comment: This will still run on each render. Needs a a dependency array with a `useCallback`-wrapped `startCar`.

Comment: Also, `el.removeEventListener('...', e => handler(e))` will fail to remove the listener added by `el.addEventListener('...', e => handler(e))`. The handlers are compared by reference, so are judged to be different. They need to be passed as `handler`, not `e => handler (e)`, hence the need to include `handler` in the dependency array and therefore the need to use `useCallback` to prevent unnecessary renders.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you change state (`setX()`, `setY()`), the component is re-rendered. What this means is that you are adding a new event listener every time you press a key. As this continues to happen, you are creating exponentially more listeners until the browser freezes.

You will need to remove your `addWindowListener()` from within your component so that it does not get called each time.

Answer (score 1):

As Haseeb said, you should add eventlistener and remove it in an useEffect hook.
Here is a sample and single .js sample with styled-components, created from your code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";

const Car = () => {
  const [move, setMove] = useState("Standing");
  let [x, setX] = useState(50);
  let [y, setY] = useState(50);

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", event => startCar(event))
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("keydown", event => startCar(event))
    }
  },[])

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log(x,y,itemStyle);
  }, [x,y])

  function startCar(event) {
    // console.log(event);
    
    switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 38:
        setY(prev => prev - 2);
        setMove("Moving to up")
        break;
      case 40:
        setY(prev => prev + 2);
        setMove("Moving to down")
        break;
      case 37:
        setX(prev => prev - 1);
        setMove("Moving to left")
        break;
      case 39:
        setX(prev => prev + 1);
        setMove("Moving to right")
        break;
    }
  }

  let itemStyle = {
    top: y + "%",
    left: x + "%",
  };

  return (
    <Main>
      <h1 id="move">{move}</h1>
      <AbsDiv>
        <MyCar style={itemStyle} />
      </AbsDiv>
    </Main>
  );
};

const Main = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-coontent: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: brown;
`;
const AbsDiv = styled.div`
  position: absolute;
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -250px;
  margin-left: -350px;
  background-color: gray;
`;
const MyCar = styled.div`
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: goldenrod;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
`;

export default Car;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Typescript Solution

```
// Create a listener function
const keydownListener = (event: KeyboardEvent) => {
    switch (event.key) {
        case "ArrowLeft":
            function1();
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":
            function2();
            break;
    }
};

// Inside the useEffect hook...
useEffect(() => {

    // ...add the event listener...
    window.addEventListener("keydown", (event: KeyboardEvent) =>
        keydownListener(event)
    );

    // ...then remove it.
    return () => {
        window.removeEventListener("keydown", (event: KeyboardEvent) =>
            keydownListener(event)
        );
    };
}, []); // <- Don't forget to add the [] here or it will break (freeze the website in my case)

const function1 = () => {
    // Do something here
};

const function2 = () => {
    // Do something here
};
```

To use this in vanilla javascript just remove the types.

Check out keycodes here: [www.toptal.com](https://www.toptal.com/developers/keycode)